# sessionState expire despite high value

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout, httpcontext

i have a problem with an application and the httpContext.Current.Session("list")

I would like the session never expires
in web config i've add

```
<sessionState timeout="120" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" ></sessionState>
```

but it not work.

How can i do it?

i use framework 4.0 in a web application

Answer (score 0):

`regenerateExpiredSessionId` affects only cookieless session mode as in documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.regenerateexpiredsessionid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For your purpose you can set large timeout and also check idleTimeout parameter in AppPool if your application has low activity.